# How can i check a third party plugin's version in internet explorer 11 (IE 11)?

Tags: javascript, plugins, jquery-plugins, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

We are developing web applications using .NET 4.0 and Silverlight 5. In our applications, we are using some third party plugins as well as our own product plugins. We are checking whether users have our plugins or not as well as its version is updated on or not(if user has installed the plugin) using Javascript. We can able to check successfully in previous IE versions with using Plugin Array. But In IE 11 we are not able to check this option. Because the Plugin Array is empty. Could you please provide us the workaround or how to check our plugin is installed or not in the client system?

In some of the forums posts and Microsoft posts are referring the IE 11 is a plugin free browser. This is scared to us. Because without these third party plugin, our sites wont work. All our products are depends on our plugins.

Could you please help us to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks and Regards,
Ragunathan Maniraj,

Answer (score 0):

Let's step back. IE11 is the *first* version of IE to populate the `navigator.plugins` array. Prior versions always defined this object as an empty array.

However, in order for it to work your plugin must be registered in the registry in the `NavigatorPluginsList` registry key. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.

Speaking more generally, IE10 on Windows 8 [introduced many new restrictions on plugins](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/09/26/windows-8-internet-explorer-10-activex-control-changes-and-restrictions.aspx), and IE11 increases these limits even further by default by enabling Enhanced Protected Mode on the desktop.